# EventCallback<dynamic> throws RuntimeBinderException

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-server-side, blazor-client-side

Using the default template I modified the Counter :

```
@code {
    private int currentCount = 0;

    private async void IncrementCount()
    {
        currentCount++;

        await UpdateCallback.InvokeAsync(new { Counter = currentCount });
    }

    [Parameter] public EventCallback<dynamic> UpdateCallback { get; set; }
}
```

And I am using it like this:

```
<Counter UpdateCallback="(d)=>MyCallback(d,42)"></Counter>

@code {

    public void MyCallback(dynamic val, int number)
    {

    }
}
```

This leads to

> Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException: 'Cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to 'object''

If I pass around a `Tuple<dynamic>` it works.

Why is that?

Answer (score 0):

You invoked using InvokeAsync so it is expecting a method which will return task not void. Use this where you used your Counter component, i think that will solve your problem.

```
<Counter UpdateCallback="async (d)=> await MyCallback(d,42)"></Counter>

@code {

    public async Task MyCallback(dynamic val, int number)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks but can you explain why it works when passing around a Tuple<dynamic>? public void MyCallback(Tuple<dynamic> val, int number) is also returning void instead of Task.

Comment: I thinks reason is dynamic type which a special type you can user others type not only Tuple<dynamic> that will work fine. I was testing a bit, using <Counter UpdateCallback="(d)=> { MyCallback(d, 42); }"></Counter> or <Counter UpdateCallback=" MyCallback"></Counter> working fine. I think problem while encapsulating a function for UpdateCallback.